# Count and SUM 10 columns mysql

Tags: php, count, sum

Table Name: controleconserto

[image: Table Name controleconserto]

I need to count how many times the "motivo" is repeated in each column and after adding the count and MAX () to find the highest value of each "motivo"

Like, but in all columns.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(motivo1) AS Total, 
    motivo1 AS reason1 
FROM 
    `controleconserto` 
WHERE 
    fornecedor = 1 
GROUP BY 
    motivo1
```

Output:

```
Total | Reason
------+-------
  3   | C1
  1   | C12
  4   | C16
  1   | C6
  3   | C7
  2   | C8
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(total) 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(motivo1) AS total 
     FROM `controleconserto` 
     WHERE fornecedor = 1 
     GROUP BY motivo1) AS final
```

Output:

```
MAX(total)
----------
4
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: please explain more what you want